# How can I rotate a sphere around a cube in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I`ve seen different options to rotate objects but I don`t know how to apply them. I am very new to javascript. I created the cube and the sphere and managed to make the sphere rotate around its own axis but I need it to rotate around the cube  Any help is welcome. 
This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100,    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            camera.position.z = 25;

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var texture = loader.load('crate.jpg');
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 7, 7, 7 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            cube.rotation.x += 0.6;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.6;

            scene.add( cube );

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var texture = loader.load('earth.jpg');
            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 50, 50 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture} );
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            scene.add( sphere );

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
                sphere.position.set(6, 0, 15);
                sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would suggest to use an `Object3D` as a container for your sphere. Then place this container at the position/center of the cube and rotate it.

```js
...
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

cube.rotation.x += 0.6;
cube.rotation.y += 0.6;

scene.add( cube );

...
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

sphere.position.set(0,0,15); // offset from center

var sphereContainer = new THREE.Object3D();
sphereContainer.add( sphere );

sphereContainer.position.copy( cube.position ); // optional, in case you've set the position of the cube

scene.add( sphereContainer );

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );

    sphere.rotation.y += 0.01; // rotate around its own axis
    sphereContainer.rotation.y += 0.01; // rotate around cube

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

Comment: I copied the code and it seems to be good and straightforward but it doesn`t work. The error I am getting is "sphereContainer is undefined" 
although it is defined.

Comment: I just see that I forgot `new` when defining sphereContainer. So I edited it to `new THREE.Object3D()`. I hope it works now. Your solution seems like a lot more computation each frame.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work. I used the rotateAboutWorldAxis function and it looks like this:

```
...
sphere.position.set(0,0,15); // offset from center

function rotateAboutWorldAxis(object, axis, angle) {
            var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
            rotationMatrix.makeRotationAxis( axis.normalize(), angle );
            var currentPos = new THREE.Vector4(object.position.x, object.position.y, object.position.z, 1.5);
            var newPos = currentPos.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix);
            object.position.x = newPos.x;
            object.position.y = newPos.y;
            object.position.z = newPos.z;
            }
```

and in the render function put:

```
var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0,50,0);
rotateAboutWorldAxis(sphere,yAxis,Math.PI / 180);
```